# eclipse .conf files coloring syntax (highlighting)

Tags: eclipse, ide, syntax-highlighting

I haven't found an easy way to add a simple syntax to Eclipse, regarding conf files.

I took a look at xText, but seems really complex for something really simple.

I basically want to color the lines beginning with `#` and `=` operators.

The conf file comes from the play framework if that matters.

I would like to stay within Eclipse and not edit it in another editor if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I didnt look hard enough...

play! framework provides a syntax coloring plugin with their framework :O, it worked fairly well, just tweaked it a little so it stays consistent with the color themes plugin (using the wombat theme :) ).

link: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1.1/ide

> Additionally, an Eclipse plugin is
>   available in your Play distribution,
>   in the support/eclipse/ directory. To
>   install it, simply copy the JAR file
>   you will find to your Eclipse
>   installation’s dropins folder.

Answer (score 2):

I used a coffee script plugin for eclipse to open the .conf file.
It fulfills the requirement. Though I know that is not the standard way to do it.

**Edit 1 :**
Found another more suitable alternative. According to Play framework documentation, the conf (Typesafe config) file uses **HOCON format**.

**[Eclipse plugin for Typesafe Config files](https://github.com/dragos/typesafe-config-eclipse)** - is available in Github.

*This is working nicely with my eclipse Neon. However I kept myself away from converting the project into an xtext project as I'm unaware of the consequences.*